# Как добавить кастомный роутинг в WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Суть такая: есть кастомный тип записи `online`. Там список магазинов, у них есть своя страница (single-online). Есть страница reviews, туда я вывожу список магазинов (Online) и мне надо, чтобы по ссылке  магазина на странице `reviews` переходило на `/reviews/название магазина`. Т.е., чтобы были пути `/online/название магазина` и `/reviews/название магазина`.

Comment: Это плохо для индексации поисковиками - дублирующийся контент. Не надо так делать.

Comment: Роутинг тут не причём (если ты его не поломал ранее). Надо просто создать нужные шаблоны

Comment: @SeVlad Роутинг точно не ломал, просто не знаю как создать single-шаблон для reviews чтобы ссылка работала. Т.е. я сделал single-reviews но по ссылке /reviews/1 показывается страница /reviews/

Comment: @kagg-design там ничего дублироваться не будет, кроме названия ссылки второго уровня и title будет разный

Comment: Цифровые слаги - это пагинация